# Create Directory For Test Unit C++ [Code::Blocks]

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Currently i am about finishing my school project, however the last thing need to be done are documentation. i am getting confuse about unit Testing, basically what i know is, i need a `testfile.cpp` for every class i created.  but i dont know where to put the file since my tutor told me to have a `main()` inside the `testfile.cpp` but isn't a project can only have one `main()` ??

Are there any possible way i can create a new folder and name it TestingFolder for example, and then put the `testfile.cpp` inside but still can be executed to proof.

Please Comment if any of the question are not clear, i am new to C++ and Documentation, apologize.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple `main()` functions. But you can create a specific `namespace` for each `main()` function for all cpp test files.

*testfile.cpp*

```
namespace test 
{
    TESTCASE()
    {
        ....
    }
    int main()
    {
        RUN_ALL_TESTS();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

*main.cpp* (The real main file)

```
int main()
{
    bool flag = true;
    if(flag)
    {
        test::main();
        anotherNamespace::main() // for each test files (for each class that 
                                 // should be tested)
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Where `flag` means a boolean variable if the tests are activated.
This is the solution if your teacher wants to have `main()` function in the same C++ project. Usually, for unit testing is created another project.